# Removing groups of similar records in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to wrap my head around this... (it may be simple, been a long day!)

I have a database with sometimes multiple similar records...

ie.

```
Apples 2008-09-03
Apples 2012-01-01
Apples 2013-10-24
Oranges 2012-01-04
```

What I need to do is do a query that will show only records that haven't been updated today...

So in this case, since Apples has an entry that was updated today, none of the records for the Apples should appear in the results.

Oranges should be the only record it returns.

I have a query similar to this...

```
SELECT fruit FROM fruitnames where date < CURDATE()
```

Which works to remove the record that was updated today... But it keeps the other records for Apples (obviously)...

How would I remove those results as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT fruit 
FROM fruitnames 
GROUP BY fruit
having sum(`date` = CURDATE()) = 0
```

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around the HAVING sum part... What does that line do in this case? (I'm still a mySSQL relative beginner) - the reason I ask is I'm trying to work "- INTERVAL 1 DAY" to adjust the calculation of CURRDATE and having a tough time

Comment: The `group by` makes a group of data for every fruit. For every fruit the `having` clause sums up when `date = curdate`. If that sum is zero then no date was today. (If the condition in the sum is true then this is `1`. Basically the sum adds up when the condition is true)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach

select fruit from fruitnames where fruit not in
(
    select distinct fruit from fruitnames where date = CURDATE()
)